# GoogleApiClient parameter is required

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to get current location of device, here is my piece of code

```
private void displayLocation() {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        test1 = latitude;
        test2 = longitude;

    } else {
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        test1 = latitude;
        test2 = longitude;
    }
}
```

I got and error like this

```
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.emildesign.navigationapplication/com.emildesign.navigationapplication.NavigationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient parameter is required.
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient parameter is required.
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.jx.b(Unknown Source)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.f(Unknown Source)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.nf.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at com.emildesign.navigationapplication.NavigationActivity.displayLocation(NavigationActivity.java:167)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at com.emildesign.navigationapplication.NavigationActivity.onCreate(NavigationActivity.java:51)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-04 07:24:33.500: E/AndroidRuntime(5427):     ... 11 more
```

it say java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient parameter is required.
Line 167 is : mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation to get last known fused location in 6 lines of codes.

Now I cannot see how you defined mGoogleApiClient, but you need to create it using a builder, something like:

```
    new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ctx)
   .apiClientBuilder.addApi(LocationServices.API)
   .addConnectionCallbacks(apiClientConnectionCallbacks)
   .addOnConnectionFailedListener(apiClientConnectionCallbacks).build();
```

Comment: The link You give, is that for Android Studio? because im using Eclipse Kepler for the platform. can you send me another link for Eclipse?
Thanks..

Comment: Yea sorry, I'm afraid that it will only work for Android Studio. Do not have a link to a jar or the like that can be used in eclipse. I would strongly recommend moving to Android Studio though, they can import Android projects from eclipse directly and the keymap can be changed to mimic eclipse, that made me able to switch rather quickly.

Comment: You can download the aar from here [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/pl/charmas/android/android-reactive-location/0.5/android-reactive-location-0.5.aar)